# Include losses defined in layers using trainable parameters into the final loss for optimization

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

Hi I am trying to create a VariationalDenseLayer where the KL loss is computed in the call function.

```
def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
    kernel_sigma = tf.math.softplus(self.kernel_rho)
    kernel = self.kernel_mu + kernel_sigma * tf.random.normal(self.kernel_mu.shape)

    bias_sigma = tf.math.softplus(self.bias_rho)
    bias = self.bias_mu + bias_sigma * tf.random.normal(self.bias_mu.shape)

    self.add_loss(self.kl_loss(kernel, self.kernel_mu, kernel_sigma) +
                  self.kl_loss(bias, self.bias_mu, bias_sigma))

    outputs = gen_math_ops.MatMul(a = inputs, b = kernel)

    if self.use_bias:
        outputs = nn_ops.bias_add(outputs, bias)

    if self.activation is not None:
        outputs = self.activation(outputs)

    return outputs


def kl_loss(self, w, mu, sigma):
    variational_dist = tfp.distributions.Normal(mu, sigma)
    return self.kl_weight * K.sum(variational_dist.log_prob(w) - self.log_prior_prob(w))

def log_prior_prob(self, w):
    comp_1_dist = tfp.distributions.Normal(0.0, self.prior_sigma_1)
    comp_2_dist = tfp.distributions.Normal(0.0, self.prior_sigma_2)
    return K.log(self.prior_pi_1 * comp_1_dist.prob(w) +
                 self.prior_pi_2 * comp_2_dist.prob(w))
```

however, I got following errors when I tried to defined my final loss to be neg_log_likelihhood + kl_loss:

> TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
> a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors leak out of the
> function building context by including a tf.init_scope in your
> function building code. For example, the following function will fail:
> @tf.function   def has_init_scope():
> my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
> with tf.init_scope():
> added = my_constant * 2 The graph tensor has name: dense_flipout/divergence_kernel:0

If I added

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

I'd got follow errors.  However, it is still not clear to me what I did wrong.

> loss = neg_log_likelihood + kl * kl_weight   File "/d/dev01/chungh/lib2/anaconda3-2020.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1266, in r_binary_op_wrapper
> y, x = maybe_promote_tensors(y, x)   File "/d/dev01/chungh/lib2/anaconda3-2020.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1202, in maybe_promote_tensors
> ops.convert_to_tensor(tensor, dtype, name="x"))   File "/d/dev01/chungh/lib2/anaconda3-2020.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py", line 163, in wrapped
> return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/d/dev01/chungh/lib2/anaconda3-2020.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1566, in convert_to_tensor
> ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)   File
> "/d/dev01/chungh/lib2/anaconda3-2020.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py",
> line 339, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
> return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)   File "/d/dev01/chungh/lib2/anaconda3-2020.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py",
> line 264, in constant
> return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,   File
> "/d/dev01/chungh/lib2/anaconda3-2020.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py",
> line 281, in _constant_impl
> tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(   File "/d/dev01/chungh/lib2/anaconda3-2020.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py",
> line 457, in make_tensor_proto
> _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)   File "/d/dev01/chungh/lib2/anaconda3-2020.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py",
> line 336, in _AssertCompatible
> raise TypeError("Expected %s, got %s of type '%s' instead." % TypeError: Expected float32, got <function neg_log_likelihood at
> 0x2aab06930b80> of type 'function' instead.

The code to compute the final loss is:

```
def neg_log_likelihood(y_obs, y_pred, sigma=noise):
    dist = tfp.distributions.Normal(loc=y_pred, scale=sigma)
    return K.sum(-dist.log_prob(y_obs))

kl = sum(model.losses)
loss = kl * kl_weight

model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.08), metrics=['mse'])
```

Any helps and pointers are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already checked the [variational layer implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/layers/DenseVariational) in Tensorflow.

You could refer to [this sample implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69389377/2063526) that uses FlipOut layers instead.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29960833)