# Rare error when using tf.function in an abusive setting

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-xla

I have programmend a framework that concatenate different ( quite complicated ) linear operators in an abstract manner. It overrides the operators, "+,*,@,-" and chooses a path through the graph of compositions of functions. It isn't easy to debug to say the least, however the control flow isn't depending on the data itself and of course any operation is done with tensorflow. I was hoping to use tf.function to compile it and get an ( hopefully much faster) tf.function by XLA. However I get the following error:

```
TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a
tf.init_scope in your function building code.
For example, the following function will fail:
  @tf.function
  def has_init_scope():
    my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
    with tf.init_scope():
      added = my_constant * 2
The graph tensor has name: Reshape_2:0
```

I do not use the tf.init_scope anywhere and there are 8 (!) google results regarding to this error - while none of them provides me any clue how to debug it.

```py
    # initilize linear operators, these are python objects that override __matmul__ etc.
    P = ...
    A = ...
    # initilize vectors, these are compatible python objects to P and A 
    x = ...
    y = ...

    # This function recreates the python object from its raw tensorflow data. 
    # Since it might be dependend on the spaces and
    # they also need to be set up for deserializaton the method is returned by a function of x.
    # But since many vectors share the same spaces I was hoping to reuse it.
    deserialize = x.deserialize()
    
    # We want to compile the action on x to a function now
    def meth( data ):
        result = P @ ( A.T @ A @ deserialize( data ) )
        # we return only the raw data
        return result.serialize()

    meth = tf.function( meth,
                       #experimental_compile = True ,
                       input_signature = (x.serialize_signature,),
    ).get_concrete_function()
    
    # we want to use meth now for many vectors
    # executing this line throws the error 
    meth(x1)
    meth(x2)
    meth(x3)
```

Needless to say that works without the tf.function.
Did anyone stumble across the error and can help me to understand it better ? Or is the hole setup I'm trying not suitable for tensorflow ?

**Edit:**

The Error was caused by implicitly capturing a constant tensor in the linear operator class by a local lambda. To be honest, the error message suggest something like that, however it was difficult to understand which line in the code caused it and it wasn't easy to find the bug in the end.

Comment: Hi! Did you try again after disabling eager execution? Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68443798/tensorflow-2-5-0-typeerror-an-op-outside-of-the-function-building-code-is-bei

Comment: Hi ! If I put this line in front I get the error in the setup:
```
RuntimeError: Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function.
```

Which is not very suprising. I pass an (tf.constant) eager tensor captured by a lambda inside P and A to the function meth is that an issue ? I was thinking, since it is only constant it can be copied and still be used readonly by the graph ?

Comment: Ok! Could you update the above code snippets to simple stand alone code to replicate the issue ? Thanks!